How to optimize / speed up calculation time with a lot of formulas?
I'm currently using google sheets to extract biographies from instagram usernames and I'm doing it for around 2500-3000 profiles a day and it takes around 18-20 hours which is a lot of time. When I try to extract only 1000 biographies at the time, it takes just 2-3 seconds, so I wanted to see if anyone could help me with speeding the process. This is the code:
=let(Σ;importxml(B1;"//meta[@name='description']/@content");regexextract(Σ;"(?s)on\s*Instagram:\s*(.*)"))

I'll also leave a sheet with the code (the code is on the cell C1) and 2500 profiles which is what i do on a daily basis.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ESuA4sVZnr9qywnx0ynZWXygV0yrgp0tQPqy1b4fYsM/edit?usp=sharing
I have no clue on how to speed it up as it takes a really long time to extract just 2-3000 profiles a day.

When I try to extract only 1000 biographies at the time, it takes just 2-3 seconds Not my experience. I tried the first 1,000 row; only about 30 rows were successfully converted; the rest have a "Loading data" error. Did all of your values convert successfully?

I would break your 3000 up into 3 batches of 1000 and process the three batches one at a time, taking 2-3 seconds per batch. I'm sure that I must be misunderstanding something in your post. are biographies the same as profiles?
